# 1040p monitor for MBP Retina via HDMI?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi

I have a MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inches, late-2013), I'm planning to buy a 1440p monitor.

1- Does my MacBook model support this resolution @60Hz via the HDMI port?

2- If so, how does it affect its overall performance?

3- If not, what's the optimal setup for a 1440p external display to be used with this model?

PS: I will use the monitor for an extended desktop, not for mirroring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it supports up to 4K at 30Hz (3840x2160) or 24Hz (4096x2160). It will work at 60Hz for 2560x1440.

Your thunderbolt (Mini-DisplayPort) supports 30Hz at 3840x2160.

I can't say how much it will affect system performance, but you do have a Intel Iris 5100 (graphics processor), so I'm guessing you'll be fine unless you're doing graphically intense things.